# md-button position alignment in the form

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, angularjs-material, angularjs-ng-include

I'm using ng-include to call my form "test_form", upon display buttons align at the center. How can I align them at the bottom right of the form?

index.html

```
<div class="col-sm-6 sidenav">
  <!-- menu bar content at the top -->
<div class="column-nav-form" ng-include = "'/views/html/test_form.html'" >
</div>
```

test_form.html

```
<form name="testForm" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FormController" class="container-fluid" ng-submit="submit()">
<!-- form labels -->
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary testForm" type ="button" ng-click ="reset()">CANCEL</md-button>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary testForm" ng-disabled="testForm.$invalid">SAVE</md-button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.md-button.md-raised.md-primary.testForm {
    position: right !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

Form button display:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pull-right class did the trick.

```
<form name="testForm" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FormController" class="container-fluid" ng-submit="submit()">
<!-- form labels -->
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary pull-right testForm" type ="button" ng-click ="reset()">CANCEL</md-button>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary pull-right testForm" ng-disabled="testForm.$invalid">SAVE</md-button>
</form>
```